# Is English Recursively enumerable?

Tags: computability, natural-language-processing, semi-decidability, computational-linguistics

The title says it all. I've tried digging up debate on this issue to see a proof one way or the other but it doesn't look like anyone is able to say whether or not it is. Clearly there are recursive structures in English, and that's about all anyone seems to say.

Comment: Do you have any formal definition of (written) English in mind? English is a constantly changing object that means different things to different people, and has no standard definition.

Comment: Y.Filmus has a point, a restricted  set of English (or any other language) is indeed RE. However natural languages are context-sensitive (in the most general sense) and dynamic and this means results like Goedel;s theorems or Turing's are not (at least directly) applicable or relevant as in formal (mostly context-free) languages

Comment: If you restrict the length of sentences to, say, 4000 words, then English is even regular (since you have finitely many words, whatever dictionary you use, and can only produce sentences of finite length, giving finitely many sentences). If you allow arbitrarily long sentences, then just saying "English" doesn't help all that much since you would need a formal grammar now to answer the question.

Comment: @G.Bach Yes, I'm reasonably sure that all natural languages are regular, because our brains can only hold a finite amount of state and can only do a finite amount of computation (eg use external storage) before we die. As natural languages are defined by their use by humans, constructs that no human can produce or understand are not part of the language.

Comment: @adrianN - It is actually known that Swiss-German is not context free. See [here](https://user.phil-fak.uni-duesseldorf.de/~kallmeyer/GrammarFormalisms/4nl-cfg.pdf).

Comment: As far as I know, Chomsky himself stated that even his type-0 model did not capture natural language. So the answer would be: no.

Comment: All that has ever been written in English is a finite set...

Comment: @vonbrand So are all known satisfiable statements, and yet they are a subset of all satisfiable sentences.